# uart sending in 8051

Tags: math, uart, bcd

In `uart`, I tried to sent in some numbers that Itried to convert to bcd and then to send.

The code works only from 00 to 99, if I want to send something bigger then 99 it will convert it to an ASCI table to some char or different number.

Could you help me to improve it so that I can to send numbers up to 255?

```
print_arr:
    mov a,@r0
    anl a ,#0f0h
    swap a
    add a , #30h
    mov sbuf , a
    jnb ti , $
    clr ti
    mov a , @r0
    anl a ,#0fh
    add a , #30h
    mov sbuf , a
    jnb ti , $
    clr ti
    mov sbuf ,#' ';
    jnb ti,$
    clr ti
    inc r0
    djnz r7,print_arr
    mov a , #0DH
    mov sbuf , a
    jnb TI , $
    clr TI
    mov a , #0AH
    mov sbuf , a
    jnb TI , $
    clr TI
    clr TR1
        ret
    end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is good, could you please use proper [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/368820) and also check the text before posting it? It will allow users to read your question easily and answer faster, thanks.

Comment: Typesettings and typos corrected. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask